# Issues with refs in react-native-modalbox [ React Native 0.61]

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

The latest version of React Native has changed how to make use of refs with this package.

For how it works now, see answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You may have experienced an error in the latest version of react-native asking if you meant to use `React.forwardRef()` for this module

The fix is to make use of react-native hooks

import the `UseRef` Hook

`import React, {useRef} from 'react';`

create a variable with it

`const modal3 = useRef();`

In the Modal prop, reference the variable `modal3` in the `ref` prop

```
<Modal
ref={modal3}>
...
</Modal>
```

Open your modal using the `open()` Method like so:

```
<Button
title="Open Modal"
onPress={() => modal3.current.open()}
 />
```

Voila !!. It works